# Kohana ORM - Incorrect table name

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-3.2

I have a weird problem with the Kohana (3.2) ORM query builder and i can't figure out what is wrong. I get "Incorrect table name" exception:

```
  Database_Exception [ 1103 ]: Incorrect table name '' [ SELECT ``.* FROM `` JOIN `user_plugins` ON (`user_plugins`.`plugin_id` = ``.`id`) WHERE `user_plugins`.`user_id` = '9' ]
```

As you can see the table is empty in the query.

Controller:

```
  $user = ORM::factory('user', Auth::instance()->get_user()->id);

  if ($user->loaded() ) 
  {
     $result = $user->plugin->find_all();
  }
```

User model:

```
  class Model_User extends Useradmin_Model_User
  {
    protected $_has_many = array(
      'plugin' => array( 'through' => 'user_plugins'),
    );
  ...
```

user_plugin Model

```
  class Model_user_plugin extends ORM
  {
     protected $_belongs_to = array(
         'plugin' => array(),
         'user' => array()
     );
  ...
```

plugin Model

```
  class Model_Plugin extends ORM
  {
     protected $_has_many = array(
         'user' => array('through' => 'user_plugins')
     );
  ...
```

Anyone got any idea what could be wrong here?
Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: What in `Useradmin_Model_User`? PS. Why do you use singular forms for relation names? It should be `users`, `plugins` etc.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm using the Mixu Useradmin module with some minor fixes(mostly to make it compitable with Kohana 3.2). You can find the source code here: https://github.com/mixu/useradmin/blob/master/classes/useradmin/model/user.php

Comment: Can you show me result of `var_dump($user)`?

Comment: Hmm, this is strange. 
I've tracked this problem to the __get function in the Kohana_ORM class. When the `$model = ORM::factory($this->_has_many[$column]['model']);` line sets the related model (around line 580 in Kohana_ORM) the _object_name variable is not set correctly and this is later used to create the second join column `$join_col2 = $model->_object_name . '.' . $model->_primary_key;`
Any idea why this fails?
Here is the dump of $user: http://pastebin.com/U63JMaR0 and here is a dump of the created $model object: http://pastebin.com/EXATcFLr

Comment: Maybe you have changed Plugin's `_initialize()` method? Whats in `Model_Plugin` code?

Comment: I solved it temporarily by setting the $_object_name in the model. `protected $_object_name = 'plugins'`.
I will have to dig deeper into this later. Thanks a lot for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how User Model should be

```
class Model_User extends Useradmin_Model_User
{
   protected $_has_many = array(
      'plugin' => array('model' => 'plugin', 'through' => 'user_plugins'),
   );
...
```

This is how Plugin Model should be

```
class Model_Plugin extends ORM
{
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'user' => array('model' => 'user', 'through' => 'user_plugins')
    );
```

You don't need user_plugin Model at all, the "user_plugins" in both models refers to the table name, not the model name. Just make sure you have the table with user_plugins that have following fields,

id, user_id, plugin_id

I hope this helps.

Comment: I made some changes to my implantation of this and know it works even without setting the $_object_name. I'm not 100% sure what caused this, but now it works so I'm happy :)

Answer (score 1):

The `$_has_many`, by convention, must always use plural names, unless you specify the name in `$_object_name` in the target model. So it should be:

```php
class Model_Plugin extends ORM
{
  protected $_has_many = array(
     'users' => array('through' => 'users_plugins')
  );
  //...
```

```php
class Model_User extends ORM
{
  protected $_has_many = array(
     'plugins' => array('through' => 'users_plugins')
  );
  //...
```

```php
class Model_user_plugin extends ORM
{
  protected $_belongs_to = array(
     'plugin' => array(),
     'user' => array()
  );
  //...
```