# Change Kohana ORM Auth table names or add prefixes

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, orm, kohana

How can I change Kohana Auth Module names (ORM driver)?

I found some information here:
[Kohana ORM - Incorrect table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627891/kohana-orm-incorrect-table-name)
. But, this is not enough!

What about roles and other tables? This is very important question, cause I'm working with existing database and tables user and roles already exist! I need pefixes for example "cp_" for Kohana Auth tables!

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You can always change class names. In original ORM/Auth you have classes: `Model_Role, Model_User, Model_User_Token`. For example `class Model_Cp_Role extends Model_Auth_Role {}`. Probably you should add `$_has_many, ...` declarations for new namespace. (but first try auto-detectoin)

Comment: Thx, just changed protected $_table_name